# jQuery post form code not passing not functioning

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
  function send_quick_pm() {
    $.post('/privmsg', {
        'username%5B%5D' : document.getElementById('quick_pm_username').value,
        subject : document.getElementById('quick_pm_subject').value,
        message : document.getElementById('quick_pm_message').value,
        folder : 'inbox',
        mode : 'post',
        post : 1
    }, function(r) {
      alert('PM is sent!');
    });
  }
```

Thats the code I am using, this is the markup I am using-

```
<form id="privatemessage" class="newmessage">
  <input id="quick_pm_username" placeholder="Message To:" type="text" class="usernameinput"/>
    <input id="quick_pm_subject" placeholder="Subject:" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" maxlength="64" type="text" class="usernameinput"/>
      <textarea id="quick_pm_message" class="noThis" placeholder="Type your message here..." >     
      </textarea>
   </div>
 <div id="bottombuttons">
   <span class="button">
     <button onClick="send_quick_pm();" class="submitbutton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">Submit</button>
    </form>
      <button class="submitbutton cancelButton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">Cancel</button>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Mark up may be wrong, this is the only way I code make it look like it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9eNe/

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Yes, like fixing that `</form>`. It's hurting my eyes

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly. Are you saying a submit occurs but without values, or no submit occurs, or...? You probably need to add `type="button"` to the button, otherwise it is `type="submit"` by default and that'll clash with your attempt to use Ajax. And fix your markup - the markup in the fiddle isn't even the same as in your question. It still looks the same if you put the closing `</form>` tag after the other elements: http://jsfiddle.net/n9eNe/2/

Comment: some other guys I was talking to said I don't even need the `<form>` tags anymore, is this true or a bunch of rubbish?

Answer (score 0):

add `type="button"` to your `<button>` elements.

```
<button type="button" onClick="send_quick_pm();" class="submitbutton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">Submit</button>
<button type="button" class="submitbutton cancelButton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">Cancel</button>
```

If you don't specify it, it defaults to `type="submit"`.  This will cause your form to submit, which in turn causes the page to be refreshed.  That will prevent you from seeing the results of your `send_quick_pm` function.

---

Also, you *really* should move your closing form tag (`</form>`) to the end.  No good can come from overlapping/interleaving elements as you've done here.

Comment: yeah sorry bout that `</form>` my bad, I did not realize that. Though yes it is incorrect markup, though it did work with out using the Ajax script. so add `type="button"` i will try that

Comment: Ok so I changed to `type="button"` but now the script does nothing at all. I get a console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: send_quick_pm is not defined`
`onclick`

Comment: that's because your function is being defined inside a `$(document).ready(function() {...})` or an onLoad handler, so it's not being declared globally.  If you're testing it on jsFiddle, under "Choose Framework", change "onLoad" to "no wrap (head)".

Comment: just define the function `send_quick_pm` in a script tag inside the `<head>` of your html document.

Comment: ok yeah I got you now. Ok so I did that, and I get the alert finally. But no messages in my inbox. Why is this?

Comment: sorry, there's not enough information here to help you with that. It's really a separate question anyway.

Comment: Well it means that the script above is not passing correctly. Like something giving it an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the form from being submitted by adding a preventDefault.

And as @Lee pointed out, fix the markup!

http://jsfiddle.net/n9eNe/4/

```
$("#privatemessage").on("submit", function(e){
    $.post('/privmsg', {
        'username%5B%5D' : document.getElementById('quick_pm_username').value,
        subject : document.getElementById('quick_pm_subject').value,
        message : document.getElementById('quick_pm_message').value,
        folder : 'inbox',
        mode : 'post',
        post : 1},
        function(r) {
          alert('PM is sent!');
        });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```